# Comparing the values (list) of Pyspark dataframes

Tags: python, pyspark

I would like to make a comparison between two df1 df2 dataframes on the list_id column :

```
df1 = 
+---------+
|  list_id|
+---------+
|[1, 2, 3]|
|[4, 5, 6]|
|[7, 8, 9]|
+---------+
df2 =
+------------+
|     list_id|
+------------+
| [10, 3, 11]|
|[12, 13, 14]|
| [15, 6, 16]|
+------------+
```

The desired result is:

```
df2 =
+-------------------+
|            list_id|
+-------------------+
| [1, 2, 3, 10, 11] |
| [4, 5, 6, 15, 16] |
| [7, 8, 9]         |
| [12, 13, 14]      |
+-------------------+
```

My aim is to concatenate lists where their intersection is not empty and to keep the others as is with pyspark.

Note: my dataframes are very large, the use of a join with Spark Sql is impossible.

Comment: what if there are multiple matches between the two dataframes?

Comment: What have you tried so far.?

Comment: I tried to make a full join with a function of intersection between the columns of the lists, which generates a memory error

Comment: I would be careful with statements like impossible...

Comment: 7,8,9 ?.. is this valid?

Comment: 7.8,9 is valid because none of them exists on a list of df2

Comment: what version of spark?

Comment: Then the question is a little vague. I have edited the question to be more precise.

Comment: [15, 3, 16] would mean what in terms of outcome? Can you add a little more data?

Comment: what if the first row in df1 is `[1,2,4]` instead of `[1,2,3]`? so there are duplicate numbers between rows in the same dataframe, are you looking to merge them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a code which works without any join operation.
It is somehow a pretty messy and I don't know how it will behave memory wize considering I'm exploding the array multiple times.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df1 = (sc.parallelize([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)])
         .toDF(('c1', 'c2', 'c3'))
         .select(F.array(F.col('c1'), F.col('c2'), F.col('c3')).alias('id_list'))
        )

df2 = (sc.parallelize([(10, 3, 11), (12, 13, 14), (15, 6, 16)])
         .toDF(('c1', 'c2', 'c3'))
         .select(F.array(F.col('c1'), F.col('c2'), F.col('c3')).alias('id_list'))
         )

out = (df1.union(df2)
         .withColumn('key1', F.explode('id_list'))
         .withColumn('key2', F.explode('id_list'))
         .groupBy('key1')
         .agg(F.sort_array(F.collect_set(F.col('key2'))).alias('id_list'))
         .withColumn('key1', F.explode('id_list'))
         .withColumn('max_length', F.max(F.size('id_list')).over(Window().partitionBy('key1')))
         .where(F.col('max_length')==F.size('id_list'))
         .select('id_list')
         .distinct()
    )
```

Comment: I tested your solution, but I had an error : 

ExecutorLostFailure (executor 11 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx on host: xxx-node-xxx. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: [2019-10-01 15:28:55.322]Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
[2019-10-01 15:28:55.322]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143. 
[2019-10-01 15:28:55.323]Killed by external signal

Comment: That's a memory error. I don't have time right know to think about a more optimized solution.
Try to adapt your memory allocation first/if you can. It will help

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I use the maximum of the memory of the cluster but I always have the same error.
do you think you have to partition the dataframes further?

Comment: If runtime is not a major concern, I would say yes.
But your problem is basicaly to construct a graph so you may try to approach it differently. I am not familiar at all with those subjects, especially while working on spark.

Comment: You can also subdivide the stuff into smaller DF and write the results incrementally. The example is poor as I cannot see if there is a positional dependency or not.